# How does one get sugarcane seeds in a map that does not natively "support" sugarcane?

Tags: pc, farming-simulator-2019

As the question suggest.....

I want to branch out my operations into sugarcane farming, but for the life of me cannot find sugarcane seeds or chutes. The map in question is Felsbrunn. From my understanding, Felsbrunn does not natively "support" sugarcane, which is why I can't any sugarcane chutes in game. How does one get sugarcane seeds or chutes in game? Is there an .XML file that I need to edit to get sugarcane chutes into my save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel kinda dumb posting this question in the first place, but I am going to leave it here in case anyone else wishes to view it in the future.

As it turns out, the in-game store sells pallets of Sugarcane that can be used for sowing on fields, which means that you don't need to edit XML files at all.

Of course, the last place I thought to look had the answer I was waiting for. Just goes to show ya, I guess. :/